# Precision of the edge of a cube versus the volume of a cube

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis, volume

The edge of a cube was measured with 1% precision. How is the precision of the volume of same cube calculated on the basis this measurement? Is it true that precision of the measurement would be 3%?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. It all depends on what you mean by "precision", which is an engineering concept rather than a physics concept. This would be best asked on the [Engineering site](engineering.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that the object is a cube (that is, you are sure that the three dimensions are identical to a much greater precision than your measurement), then the answer is "yes", because the volume V is related to the dimension of the side $d$ by

$$V = d^3$$

And for an uncertainty $p$ in the measurement, we can express the dimension of the side as

$$d=d_0(1±f)$$

where $d_0$ is the actual dimension, and $f$ is the fractional error. Then the calculated volume is

$$V = d_0^3(1±f)^3 \approx d_0^3(1±3f)$$

Thus the error in the volume is three times the error in the dimension of one side.

If you measured the three edges *independently*, and your precision for each measurement was $f$, then your error might be positive for one edge and negative for another; in general, they "partially cancel" and the error terms would result in a $\sqrt{3}f$ error in the volume.

So "it depends" - but as you formulated the problem, the interpretation I gave is reasonable; and in that case, the answer is "yes".